# use sbt for generate a webapp with icefaces

Tags: icefaces, sbt, mojarra

I'm new to sbt and I will generate a web application with jsf 2.0 mojarra and icefaces, but i don't know how to build the build.sbt. I try things like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.icefaces" % "icefaces" % "2.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "net.java" % "jsf-api" % "2.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "net.java" % "jsf-impl" % "2.1.2"
```

Maybe is this horrible wrong and sbt can't find the module:

module not found: com.sun.faces#jsf-impl:2.1.1-b04/ivys/ivy.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resolvers += "java.net maven 2 repo" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2" 

libraryDependencies += "org.icefaces" % "icefaces" % "2.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.sun.faces" % "jsf-api" % "2.1.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.sun.faces" % "jsf-impl" % "2.1.2"
```

This will only work with sbt 0.10+. Make sure you keep the blank lines between expressions.